# Sync identity columns between test and prod

Tags: sql-server

We have a table that holds some enumeration values and application parameters values in our app database. These records use identity columns as their primary keys. We also have DEV, TEST and PROD databases. We need to sync the primary keys between TEST and PROD databases every time we release an update.

What I want to ask is, what is the preferred method of syncing the identity columns? One option we thought of is to remove the identity property from the primary key column and manually create IDs which will all be same on DEV and PROD.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Sounds to me like a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @UweKeim when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reason to add an `Identity` property to a `PK`. Apparently `Identity` automates the way PK is generated and allows you to forget about code like `MAX(id)+1`. So if it doesn't make sense in your case (as far as I understand your values are pre-defined and codebase expects concrete values) then removing identity column should be a good solution.

Also a good practise is to add consitency checks in your datascripts and let them fail or notify if there are any conflicts. With non-identity approach it will look like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from enum_table where id = @idToInsert)
    --notify there is a conflict 
    -- else insert @idToInsert
```

In one of my projects we find out that weekly refresh between test and prod databases suites best for us, so consider investigating this variant too.

Pros:

- you will always have fresh/consistent data/schema to reproduce prod issues
- no need to remove identity column for lookup tables (in case it makes sense - like enum values can appear not only via manual scripts)

Cons:

- may not be sufficient when many teams are working on the same test env, however I feel like it depends on how good the process is organised

Hope this helps